# Actual Effect of Taking a Blacksmithing Potion

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

There are three Blacksmithing potions in the Reckoning:

[Minor Blacksmith's Craft](http://amalur.wikia.com/wiki/Minor_Blacksmith%27s_Craft)
[Greater Blacksmith's Craft](http://amalur.wikia.com/wiki/Greater_Blacksmith%27s_Craft)
[Master Blacksmith's Craft](http://amalur.wikia.com/wiki/Master_Blacksmith%27s_Craft)

And so far I have been using them in this way:

1. Swig a blacksmithing potion
2. Craft as many items as I can

**But do these potions make the items I craft better**? In what ways?

All the tooltip on the potion says is "+3 blacksmithing". Does that mean the only benefit is that I can scrap higher quality gear? Or will my crafted items be better?

**Does taking one of these potions make any difference if my blacksmithing is already maxed out at 10?**

Comment: I recall Amalur having skill points that you could put towards skills; wouldn't the potion just give you three more points in Blacksmithing for a limited time?

Comment: So, if my blacksmithing is at 10, is there any reason to take the potion?

Comment: No idea!  Why not take one and see what your skills show?  If you can turn it to 11, there may still be a use for them once you've maxed out the skill.

Comment: @fbueckert Well, I tried it. I have no idea if there was an effect. But I tried taking some potions on a newbie character I rolled... and, actually, I have no ideas what these potions do at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't think there is a benefit once you max your skill in an area to taking a skill potion. At least I don't recall one when taking a potion that pushed me over my max for a skill.

Comment: Darn. I was really hoping for a way to make super-powerful gear. I have terrible luck on random drops to scrap for parts.

Comment: Level 10 crafting the the top level. It may affect the random bonuses in crafting, but the base level is determined by the parts used.